# can not detect NAS

Tags: samba, fstab, cifs, nas

After the latest kernel update to Mint 20.1 my NAS is no longer discovered. My backup util mounts the windows share and that shows in nemo, plus I can go up the directory and mount other shares from the dir mounted by backup. But trying to discover the nas drive from nemo (or any of the file mangers!) doesn;t work, neither does trying to auto mount from Fstab.

I'm using this line in Fstab:

```
smb://NAServer/public /media/NAServer/public cifs guest,uid=1000,isocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm 0 0
```

and trying to mount it with root I get the error message:

> Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount
> smb://NAServer/public

I get the same result if I explicitly use the server uRl 192.168.1.XX as well.

Trying to mount it as normal user I get the err:

> mount: /media/NAServer/public: operation permitted for root only.

despite file permissions set to user.

It looks as if the NAServer isn't detectable, except by the backup util. However, it **is** detectable using a windows box.

System:
Kernel: 5.4.0-107-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2
tk: Gtk 3.24.13 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa
base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: Hello. Mint is not Ubuntu and is not supported on this Ubuntu only site. Sorry.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Ubuntu & *flavors* of Ubuntu are *adjustment* free. When code needs to be altered, it's modified & re-compiled, and no run-time adjustments (or *hacks*) are executed because they use their own packages, not an upstream package they cannot control. Mint is a different system that has the *adjustments* done that Ubuntu people may not be fully aware of, nor the added security implications of them etc... You're best seeking help fully aware of your system & it's design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issue that I can see:

This is the wrong syntax - get rid of the "smb:" part:

> smb://NAServer/public /media/NAServer/public cifs
> guest,uid=1000,isocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm
> 0 0

And this is happening becase you don't have the "user" option in your fstab declaration:

> mount: /media/NAServer/public: operation permitted for root only.

This is better I think:

```
//NAServer/public /media/NAServer/public cifs guest,user,uid=1000,isocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm 0 0
```